# Button needs two clicks for action

Tags: sapui5

I have a SAPUI5 Table to show data from a SAP Odata service. In every row I have a textfield to change the amount of the products. Next to the field is a save button to save changes using 2-way-binding. The problem is, that it needs two clicks to do anything and then it triggers the update method within SAP correct but also triggers the create method (and I don't know why). 
Do you have any ideas?

```html
  onPressSave: function(evt) { 
   var that = this;
   var oApp = that.byId("myApp");
   var oModel = that.getView().getModel("myModel");
   var path = evt.getSource().getParent().getBindingContextPath();
   console.log(path);
   
   oModel.submitChanges(
    function(){ 
     MessageToast.show(that._getMessage("It works!"), { duration:10000});
    }, function(err) { 
     MessageToast.show(that._getMessage("ERROR"), { duration:10000});
    } );
  },
```

```
<Table id="id" inset="false" items="{path: 'myModel>/EntrySet'}">
        <headerToolbar>
            </headerToolbar>
            <columns>
                <Column><Text text="{i18n>product}" /></Column>
                <Column width="60px" hAlign="Right"><Text text="{i18n>amount}" /></Column>
                <Column width="70px" hAlign="Right"><Text text="{i18n>pps}" /></Column>
                <Column width="33px" />
                <Column width="33px" />
            </columns>
            <items>
                <ColumnListItem>
                    <cells>
                        <ObjectIdentifier title="{myModel>MaterialName}" />
                        <Input id="cartAmount" value="{myModel>amount}" />
                        <ObjectNumber class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom" number="{parts:[{path: 'myModel>matPrice'},{path: 'myModel>matCurrency'}], type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Currency', formatOptions: {showMeasure: true}}" />
                        <Button icon="sap-icon://save" press="onPressSave" />
                        <Button icon="sap-icon://delete" press="onPressDel" />
                    </cells>
                </ColumnListItem>
            </items>
        </Table>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you share a working example on jsbin or plnkr?

Comment: I have created a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/dukahenezo/1/edit?html,js,output) to look into this, but cannot reconstruct the problem. Can you recreate the problem there?